# Plugin ‘IntelliJad’ failed to initialize and will be disabled

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, jad

After I install the plugin IntelliJad, the problem comes out when I restart Ideal,anyone knows the reason of it?
My ideal version is 2016.2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCw44.png)

Comment: have you tried https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6556-intellijad-plus?

Comment: yes，I downloaded IntelliJad Plus 13.1.0,and install plugin from disk,choose intelliJad-plus,jar,but it told me `Plugin 'IntelliJad Plus' is incompatible with this installation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatability table for [IntelliJad](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1570-intellijad) does not suggest that it is compatible with IntelliJ 2016.2.

Likewise, the compatability table for [IntelliJad Plus](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6556-intellijad-plus) does not suggest that it is compatible with IntelliJ 2016.2.

The last update on IntelliJad was in 2010 and the last update on IntelliJad Plus was in 2014.

IntelliJ has had a built-in Java decompiler since v14 (released in 2014) so given that you are using `v2016.2`, I suspect you don't actually **need** IntelliJad.

The built-in decompiler can be used by just browsing to a class file, IntelliJ will automatically decompile the class and display it with a header like this:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//
```

You can see the built-in decompiler plugin here:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use it ?I cannot find it in Ideal

Comment: If you browse to a class file IntelliJ will automatically decompile it for you. I've updated the answer to make this clear.

Comment: @XiaojingLu You can use IntelliJ IDEA decompiler from the command line to decompile jars in batch: `java -cp <IDEA_HOME>\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler <jar-to-decompile.jar> <directory-for-jar-with-decompiled-sources>`. See https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine for the command line options.